# How to merge two buckets from the same endpoint with different credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

If I had a bucket called s3://jack/ on gateway.example.com with it's own access key and secret access key, and another bucket called s3://joe/ on gateway.example.com with another access key and secret key, would it be possible to merge the buckets together, basically like a RAID 0? I wouldn't mind if I have to make my own endpoint gateway or just host anything in general. Thanks